# How i can fix an issue i am encountering on my wordpress website for system theme which has dark mode in but the background stays white?

Tags: android, wordpress, webview, elementor

**The specs and platform details**

- WordPress version - latest,
- Elementor Web Builder pro,
- WordPress theme - Hello Elementor theme

**Little story**

I am trying to implement a web app for Android using Android Studio and Kotlin and taking some help from online articles and so on. I was able to build basic stuff where the webview loads the website page in the app. The problem arose when I noticed that when the system dark mode is on of any Android app, some corners where I have used a shape divider as a wave keep being in the white background even if the system theme is dark.

here is the screenshot of it.
[screenshot of the homepage the waves are white still in dark mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fd1KQ.jpg)

Now i  used some workarounds in the additional CSS or that particular section using elementor builder and the css code is as below

```
.elementor-shape .elementor-shape-fill {
fill: #282727 !important;
}
```

And it does fill as black but it does so even when the light theme is on, so I want to implement it only when the system's dark mode is on, that section goes dark, and when it is using the light theme the section loads normally in white background. Luckily I found some help from chatGPT free version and it gives me some code as below

```
  @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
   .elementor-shape .elementor-shape-fill {
    fill: #282727 !important;
  }
}
```

But unfortunately, it does not work at all. So the thing is, if I am able to solve this issue, my android web app is ready fully and I so damn want this done. I spent 9 hours in a row and i really don't know what i should do .. please help me guys. For the record, I have already implemented my webview to use white background using the below function which i call post oncreate method.

```
 @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
fun loadweburlfunction () {
    webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
  //  webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
    webView.loadUrl(weburl)
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: You have to write script in JavaScript And Also One Communication Class In Android Then you will be able to do it

Comment: @chiragthummar So i found that the main issue is with the shape devider like shared in screenshot, instead of making all adjustment in an Android web app, is there possibility to fix  that on website side? i used the same code in additional CSS section but it does not work in elementor builder too

Comment: I am not very experienced in frontend